# Composer (Phar error) with Php 7.1.17

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run the command: `composer install`

> ```
> You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
> Nothing to install or update
> Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
> Generating autoload files
> ```

When I run the command: `sudo composer install`

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found in
>   /usr/bin/composer:23

This is the output of php -i

```
   > Phar
    > 
    > Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled Phar EXT version => 2.0.2 Phar
    > API version => 1.1.1 SVN revision => $Id:
    > 898d1dac303a2eedebae7b6c8fa859253b781100 $ Phar-based phar archives =>
    > enabled Tar-based phar archives => enabled ZIP-based phar archives =>
    > enabled gzip compression => disabled (install ext/zlib) bzip2
    > compression => disabled (install pecl/bz2) Native OpenSSL support =>
    > enabled
```

Can  somebody help me ?

Comment: Is that the output of a CLI run of `phpinfo`?

Comment: The shell version of PHP and the one for your webserver do not always share the same configuration. What does `php -v` output?

Comment: @NicoHaase to clarify I edited the question

Comment: Why do you run `composer` using `sudo`? What does `sudo php -i` output?